# Convert dll to csproj ou sln

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflector

I work on a existing ASP.NET MVC project. The solution uses the FluentNHibernate component(v 1.0.0).

Someone in the former team (solution was MVC2) that worked on it modified the component sources (in order to change a behavior). That modified and compiled dll was included in the MVC solution.

Now, I converted the solution to the MVC 5, and updated the existing libraries via NuGet packages. Unfortunately, I can't do it the same with FluentNHibernate component, because if I update it, it looses the modified behavior, and produces errors if I use a newer version.

The sources of the modified component aren't available. What can I do?

I decided to obtain the FluentNHibernate version 1.0.0 from the gitHub, compare the project files, note the differences, and include it in the actual (v 1.4.0.0) FluentNHibernate code.

In order to compare the differences, I need to obtain the original code from the (modified) dll.

Is there a add-in or something that could **convert a dll to a project**?
I know (and I use) the RedGate's **Reflector**, but I would like to obtain all necessary **c# files** from the dll, and not just view a class definition code.

Comment: JetBrains dotPeek or Telerik JustDecompile can make all C# files and project file from a dll (if it can be decompiled)

Comment: don't expect a readable code using dotPeek :b

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob why ? I just tested it, and code is perfectly readable. If it hasn't be ofuscated obviously ;) JustDecompile is a little better but sometime it can't decompile when dotPeek can. Just test with both and choose better result ;)

Comment: @Xaruth, could you make an answer to resolve the problem? I installed JustDecompile, seems to work

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob: I just tested dotPeek. The result is similar to the JustDecompile. The code is readable. But it added code for... Anonymous types :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dll has be created in .NET langage (C# / Vb.NET), it can be decompiled with some tools, like JetBrains dotPeek or Telerik JustDecompile. These tools can make all C# files and project file from a dll (or a exe).

Be carefull if your dll/exe has been obfuscated, the result code will be hardly readable (you'll have to use rename a lot).

In dotPeek and JustDecompile, right click on loaded dll, and choose "Create Project" (or "Export to project"). You'll get all C# files (or vb.net) and project file.

In some case, one of these tools will not be able to decompile. You can test another tools, it can work ...

Comment: some obfuscated tools can avoid decompile, like Eazfuscator. Just try and see if it works ;)

Comment: I used JustDecompile, and its worked to transform the dll to a solution... Unfortunately this almost does not help me, because the unmodified files(from github) and modified(from dll) are hardly comparable. The functions are differently located, so  compare tools like WinMerge are not very useful...

Comment: Transformation Code->IL->Code make some differences. You can try to compil new version and decompile from same tools (JustDecompile), so instead of compare IL->old code with new code, you'll compare IL->old code with IL->new code. You can have less difference, or it can just be useless...